# Creating a OS X Cocoa App Web View in Xcode 5.0.1

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5

I created a HTML5 web app that I’m trying to wrap in a web view and submit to the Mac App Store.

I’ve done the following:

1) Opened Xcode 5.0.1 and selected “Create a new Xcode project”

2) Under “OS X” I selected “Application” then I selected “Cocoa Application” then “Next”

3) I entered a “Product Name” and a “Company Identifier” then selected “Next” (I left all the other settings untouched) then “Create”

4) Under “General” > “Deployment Info” > “Deployment Target” I selected 10.6 — because I want the app to be compatible with all versions of OS X that support the Mac App Store

5) I clicked “MainMenu.xib” and selected “Window - My App”

6) From the “Object library” I drug the “Web View” object into my window and made it fill the window size

7) I saved my project and click the Play button in the upper left corner of Xcode

**The app tries to open but freezes. I don’t get an error in Xcode but it does open “main.m” and highlight “return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);” in green and says “Thread 1: signal SIGABRT”**

**I was hoping that someone could clarify why this isn’t working? And provide me with the last step to link the web view object? I searched Google and found tutorials for iOS and a few for OS X but for different versions of Xcode.**

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

In your xib, select the "File Inspector" and make sure your xib deployment version matches your app deployment version. If you don't do this, you will have problems running your application on older deployment versions.

For your crash, if you look in Xcode's debug console, you probably see something that looks like this:

```
2013-10-31 23:07:10.654 Product[19035:303] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (WebView)
2013-10-31 23:07:10.654 Product[19035:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8eeab41c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff97daee75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8eeab2cc +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff96b83d69 _decodeObjectBinary + 2349
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff96b84f2f -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1774
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff96b8512b -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 202
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff96b83e22 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff96b832dd _decodeObject + 288
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff946985bc -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 1949
    9   Foundation                          0x00007fff96b83e22 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    10  Foundation                          0x00007fff96b832dd _decodeObject + 288
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff9469e458 -[NSWindowTemplate initWithCoder:] + 1043
    12  Foundation                          0x00007fff96b83e22 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    13  Foundation                          0x00007fff96b84f2f -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1774
    14  Foundation                          0x00007fff96b84567 -[NSSet(NSSet) initWithCoder:] + 203
    15  Foundation                          0x00007fff96b83e22 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    16  Foundation                          0x00007fff96b832dd _decodeObject + 288
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff94670780 -[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:] + 155
    18  Foundation                          0x00007fff96b83e22 _decodeObjectBinary + 2534
    19  Foundation                          0x00007fff96b832dd _decodeObject + 288
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff9467059f loadNib + 232
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff9466fb9c +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 288
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff9466f98c -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 197
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff9466f77b +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 357
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff9466b617 NSApplicationMain + 448
    25  Product                             0x00000001000012c2 main + 34
    26  Product                             0x0000000100001294 start + 52
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

In this case, this is because the app has no idea what a `WebView` is when loading the nib. You to fix this you need to link against the `WebKit` framework.

Go back to your target settings and select "Build Phases". Expand "Link Binary With Libraries" and click "+". Search for the Mac `WebKit` framework and add it. The app should be able to unarchive the `WebView` in the nib now.

[image: Location of linked libraries for a target]

Comment: Also, to help avoid using new APIs on older deployment targets (and thus causing crashes), have a look at http://www.deploymateapp.com

Comment: Totally forgot about adding the Webkit.framework that fixed the first issue. Any idea how to link the webview?

Comment: I presume you mean how do you connect the `WebView` to your code. You would do that as you would with any [IBOutlet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-connections_bindings/CreatingOutlet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009971-CH15). (The article is for iOS, but the process is the same for Mac OS.